# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null at XMLHttpRequest.handleServerResponse in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, webstorm

An input field is given to the user where he types what he wants. A Javascript runs in the background to check what the item typed by the user is present.
This is done using Ajax.

**ajaxHtml.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
    <title>Let's Go</title>
</head>
<body onload="process()">
    <h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
    Enter the food you would like to order:
    <input type="text" id="userInput">
    <div id="underInput"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**foodstore.js**

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }else{
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("can't create that object bro!");
    }
    else
        return xmlHttp;
}

function process(){

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food="+food,true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }else{
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){  
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){ 
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement; 
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
            setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        }else{
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }
}
```

**foodstore.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
    $food = $_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('tuna', 'bacon', 'beef', 'loaf', 'ham');
    if(in_array($food, $foodArray))
        echo 'We do have '.$food.'!'; 
    elseif($food=='')
        echo 'Enter a food item';
    else
        echo 'Sorry we do not sell '.$food.'!';
echo '</response>';
?>
```

However this doesn't seem to work with WebStorm and shows an error on the HTML file. When I ran this on WAMP, it works perfectly however I want to know why it did not work on WebStorm IDE and want to find a solution for it.

Comment: It also works at PHPStorm. So my guess is that paths are not correct. I mean that *foodstore.php* may be in wrong place so WEBStorm can't access it.

Comment: *"However this doesn't seem to work with WebStorm"* What do you mean by that **exactly**? Please clarify. If you are using WebStorm's built-in web server .. then WebStorm does not process .php files .. as for built-in web server to execute .php files you have to specify the path to PHP Interpreter .. which WebStorm simply does not have (only PhpStorm or full IntelliJ IDEA).